# A merchant claims a loss of 4% on coffee, but uses weight equal to 840g instead of 1000g. What profit/loss the merchant actually makes?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A merchant claims a loss of 4% on coffee, but uses weight equal to 840g instead of 1000g. What profit/loss the merchant actually makes?

Merchant is giving goods worth Rs 840g for Rs 1000. So he is making a profit of $1000-840/840=400/21$.
Now given he makes a loss. Applying successive percentage 
$400/21-4-1600/21=1248/21$
That is loss. But my answer is not right

Comment: Is the answer given in percentage or what ?

Comment: percentage 100/7% gain@callculus Am I not doing it right?

Answer (score 1):

Let CP of 1000gram coffee = 100 rupees
Therefore,
CP of 840gram coffee = 100/1000 × 840
= 84 rupees

Now, SP of 1000gram coffee
=  (100-4/100) × 100
=   96/100 × 100
=    96 rupees

Required profit℅ = 96-84/84 × 100
= 12/84 × 100
= 100/7
= 14.28℅

Answer (score -1):

Suppose the cost price of coffee is 1 Rupee per gram.

When he sells 1000 grams, he claims to make a loss of 4%. So, he claims that he is selling 1000 Rs goods at 960 Rs.

He is actually selling 840 grams. So, his actual cost price is 840 Rs.

Gain = 960 - 840 = Rs. 120

**Profit % = (120/840)*100 = 14.28%**

You can check out problem 2 here, it also deals with [cheating merchants / faulty weights](https://www.handakafunda.com/profit-loss-basic-concepts-cat-preparation/).